# Raw Queries in Laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible in Laravel to run raw database queries when loading a relationship.

When loading a relationship, I dont want all rows loaded, rather I want to load average of sum of some rows.

My plain sql looks like this :

`SELECT AVG( (service + value + cleanliness + location) / 4 ) as avg FROM reviews`

Average review is the average of sum of service, value, cleanliness, location ratings.

Is it possible to do something like this in the Model

```
    public function avg_reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Review::class)
                    ->selectRaw('AVG( (`service` + `value` + `cleanliness` + `location`) / 4 ) as avg');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the relationship definition and the query you want to run

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}
public function avg_reviews() {
    return $this->reviews()->selectRaw('AVG( (`service` + `value` + `cleanliness` + `location`) / 4 ) as avg')->get();
    // return ($this->reviews()->avg('service') + $this->reviews()->avg('value') + $this->reviews()->avg('cleanliness') + $this->reviews()->avg('location')) / 4;
}
```

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist.

Comment: did you try the second one? the commented return

Answer (score 0):

you can use addSelect query like below

```
return $this->hasMany(Review::class)
                ->addSelect(selectRaw('AVG( (`service` + `value` + `cleanliness` + `location`) / 4 ) as avg'));
```